# Include TSA Certificate in Timestamp Request

Tags: signature, certificates, pki, timestamping

I'm currently working on Timestamping and stumbled upon a parameter fRequestCerts/requestSignerCertificates/certReq that according to the documentation ([1](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.rfc3161timestamprequest?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1)) tells a TSA to include the certificate that was used to sign the timestamp token in its response.

When fiddling with this parameter I noticed that Windows behaves differently when validating self-signed TSA certificates. More specifically, when the parameter is set to true Windows apparently treats self-signed TSA certificates as trustworthy. When the parameter is set to false Windows treats them as non-trustworthy.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any more detailed information about this matter. So my questions are:

- Why exactly would I use this parameter?
- How does it influence trust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior turned out to be a vulnerability. Details about it can be found here https://about.signpath.io/blog/2020/08/26/on-the-importance-of-trust-validation.html.